# Liquid line of outdoor AC unit is cold but the suction line is at room temperature

Tags: air-conditioning

Its been a few days ago I bought a new General AC 1 Ton for my bedroom of 118 sq. feet.

From the first day of installation I never got the expected cold air from the indoor unit I asked the mechanic/ fitter why is it taking this long as it was first time for me but they said it will take a little long time for the initial start to blow the cold air from the indoor unit and they left and took the payment and I kept waiting for more than two and half hours for getting the cold air from the indoor unit but didn't got any cold air then I started diagnosing from my side I set the mode to fan and then cool to check if the temperature of the blown air has any difference in the two different modes which it should be but surprisingly the blown air are of same temperature in both mode then I tried to get more information about the ac parts and figured out about the liquid line and suction line.

So I checked while the ac is ON, the liquid (Smaller Diameter) line is very cold and sweating but the suction (Larger Diameter) line is neither too hot nor too cold its of normal temperature (i.e, Room Temperature).

Also I found that after letting the ac On for a while touching the foam coating of the liquid line near the outdoor unit is of normal temperature but touching it from the indoor side is a bit colder.

Please help me what should I do? Or whom should I complain the mechanic/ fitter or the company/ shop from where I bought?

Comment: The installer said it was operating correctly - they took payment. Contact the installer first. If the installer says the unit is bad - you can then contact the shop you purchased the unit from. Unfortunately if the shop and installer do not work together - you might have a finger point - if the unit is bad the installer will want money again to install another unit.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for that suggestion and I will do that sure but could you help me suggest what might be the issue?

Comment: With only that little bit of information it is difficult to say. This is an all in one unit. Could be orifice valve, compressor, poor charge , bad fan any myriad really as there is not enough information to properly diagnose it.

Comment: Is this unit an a/c only or is it a "heat pump" which can heat in winter? Where is this? Is the power system there a single voltage ~230 V?

Comment: @ken, right. General rule of thumb is to never hire someone to install something that *you* bought. If it doesn't go right, the store will say it was installed wrong, and the installer will say the product was faulty. They have no business or legal connection with each other, so it's all on you to resolve the impossible situation. It will cost more, but you should always either have the store install their own product, or hire someone to provide *and* install the product. Either way, you have a one-to-one relationship and a simple legitimate argument in small claims court when things go wrong.